# Windows 7 and Openssl: creating p12 file

Tags: ios, windows, flash, openssl

This used to work on my last computer, but I created a CSR and uploaded it to Apple and it returned a valid distribution certificate.  But when I run OpenSSL to try and create the p12 file, I keep getting this error:

```
"no certificate matches private key".
```

My batch file looks like this:

```
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg
set RANDFILE=.rnd
openssl x509 -in ios_distribution.cer -inform DER -out developer_identity.pem -outform PEM
pause
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -out myfile.p12
pause
```

I've tried just about everything, and I'm seriously stuck.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try specifying Apple's WWDRCA certificate in your export command?

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in developer_identity.pem -certfile AppleWWDRCA.cer.pem -out myfile.p12
```

Alternatively, you can use an online tool like [Mobundler](http://mobundler.com) too

Comment: Mobundler worked!  Thank you!

Comment: A year later - where did Mobundler go? Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You are running two commands. The first converts a certificate from DER format to PEM. The second accepts the converted certificate and converts it to PKCS12 adding the private key to the certificate at the same time. Openssl is generating the public key from your private key **mykey.key** and trying to tell you that it doesn't match your public key **developer_identity.pem**.

Do you have any other private keys that might match? Otherwise you need to re-create your public key based on your private key. The commands are something like:

```
openssl req -new -key mykey.key -out client.csr -config openssl.conf
openssl x509 -req -in client.csr -out client.crt
```